# PHP Class Instance only returns name?

Tags: php, xenforo

So I'm extending the XenForo "SDK" to make an integration with an app I'm working on like so;

```
$dir = __DIR__;
require $dir . '/src/XF.php';

XF::start($dir);
$app = XF::setupApp('XF\Pub\App');
$app->start();

$user = XF::visitor();
```

However, there is a bit of a problem. If I use `var_dump($user)`, it outputs everything but prefixes everything with the class and its type which isn't what I want. E.G

```
object(XF\Entity\User)#435 (15) { ["_uniqueEntityId":"XF\Mvc\Entity\Entity":private]=> int(5) ["rootClass":protected]=> string(14) "XF\Entity\User" ["_useReplaceInto":protected]=> bool(false) ["_newValues":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_values":protected]=> array(34) { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["email"]=> string(21) "placeholder" ["custom_title"]=> string(0) "" ["language_id"]=> int(0) ["style_id"]=> int(0) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" ...
```

But, if I just return `$user`, I only get the class name as a return like so;

```
XF:User[1]
```

Basically, I'm trying to return the user instance as JSON with all the information that `var_dump` provides, but without all the weird prefix casting.

If I access the properties directly, e.g `$user->email`, it works, but I feel like there must be a better way than me just repeating that for each property in the whole instance.

Sorry if this is a basic question. I tried searching and couldn't find much on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "just return $user"? Do you echo it? In the var_dump output I only see protected and private properties. This means you cannot access these properties outside of the class, but var_dump will still show them.

Comment: @BramVerstraten Well essentially I want to output all of those properties, but since they are protected/private, I'm not sure the best way to go about it. Especially since this is a XenForo class, I can't simply just add onto it. Ideally, I just want to be able to grab a large amount of these properties easily, since like I said I can access them directly like `$user->email` but I can't just output them all.